# What good options exist for effectively managing Eclipse/CDT build configurations?

Tags: c++, eclipse, project-management, eclipse-cdt, buildconfiguration

We are aiming to leverage software reuse in embedded ARM/Linux platforms. Some of our hardware platforms are designed for customers' specific needs. Of course the application would be customized in various ways too.

While it is not an Android product, for one it is way too big compared to ours, it does make a good analogy in that other than the constant of being Linux based, there are different look and feel to the UI, there are different phones, there are different CPUs, there are different firmwares for different radios, etc. So there are many configurations to manage. And the configurations are a sparse matrix, in that not all combinations exist.

Continuous Integration is also not completely out of the picture in the future.

So for the near future the end point seems to be:

1. A core set of libraries that we want to keep developing and apply everywhere. Class inheritance supplies the customizations. So there is a build configuration for the application types.
2. A handful of customized ARM/Linux hardware platforms. Seems a BSP/board class HAL for our libraries is the way to go. That means a build configuration to pick the right hardware/board.
3. A handful of co-processor firmwares matching to the hardware/board, but the API to our libraries is the same. So there is a build configuration depending on the firmwares.
4. A handful of implementation for different look and feel/applications. That's another build configuration.

Needless to say there are many include paths, #define's, and file exclusions to make all these work.

So as you can see, if we wanted a collection of Eclipse/CDT projects in a workspace that allows us to build all these variants in the same environment all at once, there are a lot of configurations to create and manage in Eclipse/CDT. If the GUI is the only way to manage, there is a whole deal of mouse clicking to do. And after that there is no simple way to verify that all configurations are setup correctly without a whole lot more mouse clicking. There isn't a dashboard view. Is there a text editor based approach to manage all these?

I did try to do my homework. I understand that there is the 'Import Settings...' and 'Export Settings...' buttons in the 'Paths and Symbols' tab. But it does one configuration at a time, for one project at a time. It doesn't seem very systematic and is easy to miss something.

I have also look directly at .cprojects but I worry that if I made a mistake Eclipse will just silently do the unexpected things and will take big effort to fix.

Do fellow experts have a better suggestion?